# Make discord python rewrite bot tag message author

Tags: python-3.x, discord.py

Am updating an old bot made with Discord.py and I can't get it to tag people as it used to do.

```
if 'test' in message.content:
            msg = f'test sucessful {.author}'
            await message.channel.send(msg)
```

On the discord rewrite documentation the only example I found was with {.author}, and it doesnt work. It does print the user's name, like *person#1234*, but it doesnt tag them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are different ways of tagging a user - they are equivalent:

---

## Examples

```py
await message.channel.send(f"Test successful, {message.author.mention}!")
await message.channel.send(f"Test successful, <@{message.author.id}>!")
```

Comment: Tyvm! Last night I spent more than an hour looking for this before giving up.

Comment: Anytime! Don't be afraid to ask here again if you need anything else :) Good luck with the bot!